# I can't find the other hard drive in my computer

Tags: hard-drive

I recently installed Ubuntu 13.10 in my Windows 7 computer. My computer has 2 internal hard drives. After the installation, I can't find my 2nd hard drive. The only hard drive that shows up is the one that contains the Ubuntu OS. Seems like the 2nd hard drive is not installed or whatsoever. I don't know what to do. I'm so frustrated. What should I do?

Comment: try fixparts program.

Comment: Does it show up in the disk utility?

Comment: Please add the output of `sudo fdisk -l` to your question.

Comment: @wilf Here you go.
Disk /dev/sda: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30401 cylinders, total 488397168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00020fbc

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   486322175   243160064   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       486324222   488396799     1036289    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       486324224   488396799     1036288   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Comment: So there is no `/dev/sdb`, or anything beginning with `/dev/hd`? Check if the drive is powered, activity indicator flashing etc.

Comment: @wilf it appears no. How can I check if the drive is powered? I tried opening Disks (not Disk Utility just Disks because I can't search for that program but when I search for it in the sotware center it says its installed) and it's not there.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Where can I find that program? or where can I install it? It doesn't appear in the Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: Use terminal, run: `gnome-disks`

Comment: @Sneetsher It brings up disks. And it still doesn't list up my lost drive.

Comment: Try unplug that drive then put it back? It could be hardware problem.